# How to convert String (of length 1) to the associated int value of ASCII code (0-255)?

Tags: java, string, character

In my code I have A string with length 1,
I want to convert it to the int associated with the character value of (extended) ASCII code (0-255).

For example:

```
"A"->65
"f"->102
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int asciiCode = (int)A.charAt(0);
```

Or, if you really need to get the ascii code for the string literal "A", instead of a string referenced by variable A:

```
int asciiCode = (int)"A".charAt(0);
```

Comment: `(int) 'A'` for your second is simpler.  Incidentally, I think "I have A string" is a typo.  Perhaps Belgi meant "I have a String".

Comment: @MikeSamuel there's a real difference between "A" and 'A'.

Comment: True, but there is no difference between `"A".charAt(0)` and `'A'`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel sure there is.  If your input is a string of length 1, and you want to deal with type char primitives, you have to turn it into a char primitive by calling `charAt()` on it, instead of assuming your string input is suddenly a `char` type because that's what you need.

Comment: When is the Java expression, `"A".charAt(0) != 'A'`, true?

Comment: If you're asked to add the ints 10 and 1 in java, do you simply say the answer can be given by the int `11`, or do you say `return 10 + 1`?  Surely the equality operator `==` says they are equal so the answers must be the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4127/discussion-between-bdares-and-mike-samuel)

Answer (score 3):

You mean `char`? All you really need to do is cast the character to an int.

```
            String a = "A";
            int c = (int) a.charAt(0);
            System.out.println(c);
```

Outputs `65`

Here's a more comprehensive code.

```
  import java.io.*;
    import java.lang.*;

      public class scrap{
      public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
      BufferedReader buff =
      new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.println("Enter the char:");
      String str = buff.readLine();
      for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i ){
      char c = str.charAt(i);
      int j = (int) c;
      System.out.println("ASCII OF "+c +" = " + j + ".");
      }
      }

  }
```

Comment: I have "A" not 'A'. can you tell me how to get from "A" to 'A' ?